# Обработка результата

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Есть данные:

```
s="""#EXTINF:0,FREE8 КАНАЛ
    udp://@239.255.0.107:1234
    #EXTINF:0,Русская ночь
    udp://@239.255.6.102:1234"""
```

Нужно получит:

```
    udp://@239.255.0.107:1234 #EXTINF:0,FREE8 КАНАЛ
    udp://@239.255.6.102:1234 #EXTINF:0,Русская ночь
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Разбиваем строку методом splitlines, напримимер, а потом соединяем нужным образом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с регулярными выражениями:

```
import re
m = re.findall(r'(#.+)\n?\s*(udp:.+)\n?\s*', s, re.IGNORECASE)
for item in m:
  print "%s %s" % (item[1], item[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Так пойдет? Правда проверок здесь не делается никаких...

```
ls = s.split('\n')

for i in range(len(ls) / 2):
    print ls[i*2+1].strip() + " " + ls[i*2].strip()
```

Comment: придумалось ещё одно решение

x = s.split("\n")
map(lambda l, r: l.strip() + " " + r.strip(), x[0::2], x[1::2])

Comment: Если использовать splitlines, можно обойтись стрипов.